# how to get rational function

Tags: calculus, rational-functions

q:

> A trial was conducted on a volunteer smoker that involved the
> measurement of nicotine levels in the blood after smoking one
> cigarette.
>
> Two series of blood samples were taken.
>
> Series $A$  blood samples were taken every $4$ minutes for the first
> $30$ minutes only and series $B$ samples were taken every $10$ minutes
> for the entire $2\frac{1}{2}$ hours the experiment was conducted over.
> The nicotine level for each sample was measured in nanograms per
> millilitre.
>
> This specific model for this experiment becomes $N(t) = \frac{640t}{(t^2 + 400)}$

what is series  $A(t)$ blood samples and series $B(t)$ blood samples to get $N(t) = \frac{640t}{(t^2 + 400)}$, how do they get this rational function?,
they give one graph, is this graph plotted from N(t) or N(t) taken from this graph?

if N(t) taken from this graph how to frame this function from this graph?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxv6A.jpg)

more about this on this page [link](https://mathspace.co/learn/world-of-maths/hyperbolas-and-other-rational-functions/solve-applications-involving-rational-functions-33860/applications-involving-rational-functions-1426/)

Comment: Welcome to MSE... Please use Mathjax!

Comment: So there doesn't appear to be a theoretical model for how the concentration of nicotine, depends on ingestion of nicotine. Without a mathematical model, we cannot make mathematical predictions and derive $N(t)$. I imagine that the model $N(t)$ is found via curve fitting the experimental data. Maybe there is something that I am missing, but that is my best shot at answering your question.

Comment: @Tucker yes, I want to know how to frame this Eqn from graph data, it's taken from two graph

Comment: You would need to do some kind of "best fit" to the data and you would need to provide a trial function or functions to fit the data to.